# A simple "Hello World" in React.js not working

Tags: reactjs

I am making a simple "Hello World" program in React.js. I am expecting "Hello World" to be printed in the body of the html.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://fb.me/react-0.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello, world!</div>;
    }
});
React.render(new HelloWorld(), document.body);
</script>
</head>
<body> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Can someone tell me where am I making a mistake?

Comment: You can't use JSX (<div>Hello, world!</div>) without converting the JSX into straight JS

Comment: How to do that ... can you kindly explain pls? I know grunt ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you're missing is including something that transforms the JSX into JS. You need to include the JSXTransformer.js. Also notice the React.render doesn't use document.body, it should be a dom element. Here's an example that should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My First React Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="greeting-div"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
      var Greeting = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
          return (
            <p>Hello, Universe</p>
          )
        }
      });
      React.render(
        <Greeting/>,
        document.getElementById('greeting-div')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, a well running example ... Thnx buddy!

Comment: Thanks, mate - I missed transforming JSX to JS

Answer (score 19):

Sol's answer covers why the simple hello app doesn't execute. The best practice on the latest React.js as of Jan 2017 is to import

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

and have the script type set to `text/babel`.

With this, you can execute JSX normally e.g.

```
class Greeting extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Hello, Universe</p>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is most stable till today.

Answer (score 5):

i just thought that i would share my solution with everyone. I wanted to set up a simple project without all the npm, node guff, like the OP i was having problems, it took me three hours to figure out, below is my solution.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Boy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/babel" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">Loading...</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

The key is to include the appropriate script files from React and Babel. I am using an external app.js file, if you would like to do this then remember to include type ="text/babel".

Once done you can execute the hello world example from React. My app.js file:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

CSS file:

```
#root {
    color: skyblue;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for posting an answer. Please finish the tour and enjoy SO ;-)